# SVG reversing animation

Tags: css, animation, svg, smil

I'm still learning SMIL and one thing that bothers me is the no support for automatic reversed animations. So here's my test SVG I made quicky flor the purpose of testing SVG position animations.

In the simplest form, I want the animation to reverese back to its original starting position when reaching the end, like how the CSS animation `alternate` works.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 124 82">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <title>Untitled-5</title>
  <line class="cls-1" x1="12" y1="70" x2="44" y2="12">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="y1" from="70" to="35" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="x2" from="44" to="59" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="y2" from="12" to="56" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </line>
  <line class="cls-1" x1="44" y1="12" x2="112" y2="45">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="x1" from="44" to="59" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="y1" from="12" to="56" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="x2" from="112" to="100" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="y2" from="45" to="12" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </line>
  <circle cx="12" cy="70" r="11" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cy" from="70" to="35" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="44" cy="12" r="11" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cx" from="44" to="59" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cy" from="12" to="56" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="112" cy="45" r="11" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cx" from="112" to="100" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cy" from="45" to="12" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

As you can see, the animation runs perfectly until it reaches the end, and just skips back to the start. Unfortunately, the way I'm implementing my larger SVG has no support for JS changing the `<svg>` element.

I know this question has been asked a few times already, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423332/how-to-reverse-the-moving-direction-of-the-svg-animation-on-the-mpath) for example. They all seem to cover only the `<motionPath>` element using `keyPoints` and `keyTimes`, if there's a way to accomplish this with my SVG using motion paths that'd be fine too, I'm just not sure how.

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are on the good path with [`keyTimes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/keyTimes).
But what you need for your `<animate>` is the [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/values) attribute.

Basically, for each `<animate>`, I

- added `keyTimes = "0; .5; 1"` so that we've got our 3 way points
- converted `from` and `to` attributes to `values="from;to;from"`
- changed the `dur` to make it twice longer.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 124 82">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <title>Untitled-5</title>
  <line class="cls-1" x1="12" y1="70" x2="44" y2="12">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="y1" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="70;35;70"></animate>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="x2" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="44;59;44"></animate>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="y2" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="12;56;12"></animate>
  </line>
  <line class="cls-1" x1="44" y1="12" x2="112" y2="45">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="x1" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="44;59;44"></animate>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="y1" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="12;56;12"></animate>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="x2" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="112;100;112"></animate>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="y2" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="45;12;45"></animate>
  </line>
  <circle cx="12" cy="70" r="11" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cy" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="70;35;70"></animate>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="44" cy="12" r="11" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cx" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="44;59;44"></animate>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cy" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="12;56;12"></animate>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="112" cy="45" r="11" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cx" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="112;100;112"></animate>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cy" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="45;12;45"></animate>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

And if you want the js I made :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('animate').forEach(a => {
  a.setAttribute('keyTimes', '0;0.5;1');
  let f = a.getAttribute('from');
  let t = a.getAttribute('to');
  a.setAttribute('values', f + ';' + t + ';' + f)
  a.removeAttribute('from');
  a.removeAttribute('to');
  a.setAttribute('dur', (parseFloat(a.getAttribute('dur')) * 2) + 's');
})
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 124 82">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <title>Untitled-5</title>
  <line class="cls-1" x1="12" y1="70" x2="44" y2="12">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="y1" from="70" to="35" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="x2" from="44" to="59" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="y2" from="12" to="56" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </line>
  <line class="cls-1" x1="44" y1="12" x2="112" y2="45">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="x1" from="44" to="59" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="y1" from="12" to="56" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="x2" from="112" to="100" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="y2" from="45" to="12" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </line>
  <circle cx="12" cy="70" r="11" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cy" from="70" to="35" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="44" cy="12" r="11" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cx" from="44" to="59" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cy" from="12" to="56" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="112" cy="45" r="11" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cx" from="112" to="100" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate class="anim_1" attributeName="cy" from="45" to="12" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Very well explained as well. May I ask what program you used to move `from` and `to` into `values`?

Comment: It looks like you need to remove spaces in keyTimes like this keyTimes="0;0.5;1" to make it work in Safari (at least in Safari 9.1.3)

Comment: @eye-wonder thanks ! I always have doubts on which browser support which syntax exactly... So I followed MDN's one. Bad idea ;-) But safari 10 has no problem btw.